# Intent from one class to another in not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm creating a intent in title_page_activity.java when i run this application the titlepage appears and the application stops unfortunately.
and the DDMS says that the application doing more work on its main Thread.
please help me with this

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.hems.cqu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Title_page_activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.app.hems.cqu.MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

mainpage.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.app.hems.cqu.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="@string/contact"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/signin"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
        android:text="@string/signup"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

titlepage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/title_image"
    >

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.app.hems.cqu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle viewUserOptionPage) {
        super.onCreate(viewUserOptionPage);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);
    }


}
```

Title_Page_Activity.java

```
package com.app.hems.cqu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Title_page_activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle CreateTitleSleep) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(CreateTitleSleep);
        setContentView(R.layout.titlepage);
        Thread Timer = new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    sleep(2000);

                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.app.hems.cqu.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(openMainActivity);
                }               
            }           
        };
        Timer.start();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I just ran this, and it worked fine for me.  Try this:  `Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(Title_page_activity.this, MainActivity.class)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, `onResume` is last method of the creation of activity also check [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.app.hems.cqu.MAINACTIVITY");
        startActivity(openMainActivity);
      }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In onCreate you start a thread (good, you want to offload from the main ui), yet inside that thread you start the mainactivity again. So this will end up with an infinite loop of activity starts.

Comment: yes but inside the onCreate. So onCreate -> starts thread -> thread executes and creates a new activity -> calls another onCreate -> starts another thread -> created again a new activity. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a context inside of the intent. Try this

```
finally
            {
                Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(openMainActivity);
            }
```